# Список абонентов в отдельном файле

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asterisk

Изучаю Asterisk и на данный момент уже поднял сервер на Ubuntu, и совершаю звонки с/на устройствах. Интересует вопрос: можно ли каким-нибудь образом формировать список абонентов в отдельном файле (не в `sip.conf`)? Точнее, хочу написать web морду для того, чтобы из браузера вводить номера абонентов и их параметры, а потом сохранять в файле, чтобы не лазить каждый раз в `sip.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

можно

```
#include "/etc/asterisk/testfor.ael"
```

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/AEL+including+other+files

Answer (score 1):

`#include "users/*.conf"` - мы сделали так.

Теперь в папке `users` создаем сколько нам нужно файлов c данными с расширением `.conf`.

Астериск автоматом подгружает все конфиги пользователей.